# Correctly applying softmax in self attention layer

Tags: transformer, softmax

I'm trying to understand how to apply softmax in self attention layer.
Let's say we have Query and Key matrix where the last row is for Paddings

[image]

In this case Z = Q*K_t would be something like this:

[image]

When we add the Mask we have:

[image]

Now the problem. When I apply the softmax function to each row, I get that the last one is not going to be populated with 0s. By defining S = softmax(Z) what we get is:

[image]

To get the output Y of the self attention layer, we have to multiply S by V (Values matrix):

[image]

And as a result, we have that y41 and y42 are both functions of Padding values.
How to get rid of this problem?